# How to color specific rows in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer, tablecellrenderer

I want the ability to highlight some rows of `JTable`, depending on the values in the row itself. For example, if the *existing qty* < *reorder level*, that row should be highlighted in the `JTable`.

I know there is a table method `tblItems.setSelectionBackground(Color.yellow);` that works when the rows are selected, but is there a similar method that doesn't rely on the rows being selected to have them show in a different color?

```
public class MyTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {  
    @Override  
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
(JTable table, Object value, 
boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Object ob=table.getValueAt(row, column);
        if(ob.toString().equals("yes")){
            //need to colour the entire row
        }
        return 
    }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Comment: everything is described in the two answers here, please what do you expecting else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107545/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-particular-cell-in-jxtreetable-dynamically/12108024#12108024) to change the color of the cell. the same technique could be used to apply it to each cell in the row.

This is also example with `prepareRenderer`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import java.awt.*;

public class TableWithPrepareRendererExample extends JFrame {
  ColorName colors[] = { new ColorName("Red"), new ColorName("Green"), new ColorName("Blue"),
    new ColorName("Black"), new ColorName("White") };

  public TableWithPrepareRendererExample() {
    super("Table With prepareRenderer Example");
    setSize(500, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTable table = new JTable(new AbstractTableModel() {
      ColorName data[] = { colors[0], colors[1], colors[2], colors[3], colors[4], colors[0],
        colors[1], colors[2], colors[3], colors[4] };


      public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
      }

      public int getRowCount() {
        return 10;
      }

      public Object getValueAt(int r, int c) {
        switch (c) {
          case 0:
            return (r + 1) + ".";
          case 1:
            return "Some pithy quote #" + r;
          case 2:
            return data[r];
        }
        return "Bad Column";
      }

      public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        if (c == 2)
          return ColorName.class;
        return String.class;
      }

      public boolean isCellEditable(int r, int c) {
        return c == 2;
      }

      public void setValueAt(Object value, int r, int c) {
        data[r] = (ColorName) value;
      }

    }) {
      public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                                       int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, vColIndex);
        Object value = getValueAt(rowIndex, vColIndex);
        if (value.toString().equals("Red"))
          c.setBackground(Color.RED);
        else {
          if (rowIndex % 2 == 0 && !isCellSelected(rowIndex, vColIndex)) {
            c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
          } else {
            // If not shaded, match the table's background
            c.setBackground(getBackground());
          }
        }
        return c;
      }
    };

    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(colors);
    table.setDefaultEditor(ColorName.class, new DefaultCellEditor(combo));
    table.setRowHeight(20);
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    TableWithPrepareRendererExample ex = new TableWithPrepareRendererExample();
    ex.setVisible(true);
  }

  public class ColorName {
    String cname;

    public ColorName(String name) {
      cname = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return cname;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: whole row could be equals prepareRenderer

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd do it, is to modify the code that `JTable` uses to paint the table cells...

Implement your own `TableCellRenderer`. In the `getTableCellRendererComponent()` method, check to see whether the qty < reorder level, as you wanted, and if it is, call `setBackgroundColor()` on the `Component` before you return it from this method. The easiest way to write a `TableCellRenderer` is to look at the source code for the existing `TableCellRenderer` used by `JTable` - it only has 1 method and you can basically just copy it and add in a little bit of code to do your color-checking. You set the `TableCellRenderer` on the `JTable` using `setDefaultRenderer()`

As mentioned by @mKorbel in the comments, you could also achieve a similar thing by overwriting the `JTable` `prepareRenderer()` method.

Its not that hard to do, especially if you look at the existing Java source code to see how they do it.

Comment: whole row could be equals prepareRenderer

Comment: @chathura2020 Yes, look at my example.

Comment: can you write the code here. I tried but still can't do it. can't create the Component object.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
private JTable table;
private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

public TablePrepareRenderer() {
    Object[] columnNames = { "Type", "Company", "Name", "Salery", "Designation" };
    Object[][] data =
    { { "Probation", "Digital Research Lab", "Kamran Ali", "500,000", "Java Developer" }, { "Permenent", "Netsole",
                                                                                            "Farhan Khan",
                                                                                            "80,000",
                                                                                            "System Administaror" },
      { "Contract", "System Limited", "Danyal", "100,000", "Network Administrator" },
      { "Probation", "TeraData", "Ali Raza", "45,000", "IT Officer" },
      { "Contract", "MicroSoft", "Sikandar Hayat", "450,000", "Team Lead" },
      { "Permenent", "MicroSoft", "Adnan", "30,000", "Driver" }, };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

                if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                    if (table.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
                        String type = (String)getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
                        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Probation")) {
                            c.setBackground(new Color(198, 190, 255));

                        }
                        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Permenent")) {
                            c.setBackground(new Color(14, 255, 190));

                        }
                        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Contract")) {
                            c.setBackground(Color.green);

                        }

                    }
                }
                if (isRowSelected(row) && isColumnSelected(column)) {
                    ((JComponent)c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                }
                return c;
            }
        };

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TablePrepareRenderer frame = new TablePrepareRenderer();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocation(150, 150);
            frame.setSize(800, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);


        }
    });
}
```

}