# Java JTable, TableCellRender how to change color of the Integer value in the cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable and in one column I have integers, so they are printed to the right edge, not to the left like strings. Now I want to make it so that if my integer value is greater than x, it is drawn in red. So I did it like this:

```
public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
{
    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    if (column == 2)
    {
        Integer population = (Integer)value;

        if (population > 20_000_000)
            cell.setForeground(Color.RED);
        else
            cell.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    return cell;
}}

    ... this.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new CountryTableCellRenderer());
```

The ccolour changes but then my numbers are displayed to the left edge so they are treated as Strings. Is it possible to treat it as a Integers?

Comment: How did they get to the right edge on the first? Look at the API docs for JTable and the text alignment field. If you switch between the cell editor and the cell (an inset JLabel) the renderer instance is different and you need to call repaint() after changes and perhaps revalidate() on the component.

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098846/how-to-color-specific-rows-in-a-jtable which shows how to color an entire row, which was not what the question is asking. That duplicate was removed and replaced with another showing how to change the alignment.

Comment: The default renderer aligns the text to the left. In your custom renderer you need to change the alignment to align the text to the right. See the duplicate link for the JLabel method used to set the alignment. You may want to check out [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for reusable renderers that allow you to do basic formatting. You could then just extend the NumberRenderer and add your highlighting logic and not worry about the alignment.

Comment: Also note your renderer code should NOT check the column. This renderer should be added to the specific column: `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(???).setCellRenderer(...);`